# Calling a Controller Method from Jquery Mobile Script

Tags: apex, visualforce, jquery, remote-action, jquerymobile

**I have written the following code in salesforce**

```
<apex:page Controller="Publication_Tab_Controller" showHeader="true" tabStyle="Publication__c">
<head>

<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>

<!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"></link>

<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<apex:form >
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" id="AccountTabPanel" value="{!tabOpt}">
<apex:tab label="Invitation" name="Invitation" id="tabInvitation">
<apex:pageBlock title="Publication">  
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!pub}" var="a">  
     <apex:column headerValue="Pub-ID">  
      <apex:outputlink value="/{!a.id}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputlink>  
     </apex:column>  
     <apex:column value="{!a.id}" headerValue="Publication SFDC Id"/> 
     <apex:column >

         <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Accept invitation</a>

            <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
                  <p>These are the terms and conditions of viewing the publication.
                  </p>
                  <form>
                      <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> I agree</input></label>


                        <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit"></input>


                        <input type="reset" value="Cancel"></input>
                  </form>
            </div>
         <!--apex:commandButton value="Accpet Invitaion" action="{!switch}" reRender="AccountTabPanel"/-->


     </apex:column> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>     
   </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="View Publication" name="ViewPublication" id="tabViewPublication">
</apex:tab>
<apex:tab label="Approve" name="Approve" id="tabApprove">
</apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
                      <script name='Name'>
                             var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

                            j$(document).ready(function(){
                                j$("#Submit").click(function() 
                                    {

                                     Publication_Tab_Controller.update_publication(a);
                                    });

                              });
                          </script>                      
</apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

**Along with the controller**

```
public class Publication_Tab_Controller{
    public list <publication__c> pub {get;set;}
    public Publication_Tab_Controller() {

    String searchquery='select name,id from publication__c';  
    pub= Database.query(searchquery); 
    }
    public Publication_Tab_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    }
    public String tabOpt {get;set;}

    public void switch()
    {
        tabOpt='Review';
    } 
    @RemoteAction
    public static void update_publication(publication__c publication)
    {
        publication.AcceptInvitation__c='Accepted';
        update publication;
    }

 }
```

But I am not being able to access the update_publication(publication__c publication) from the script.  I just started learning salesforce and any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_configuring_request.htm
the correct JavaScript syntax for calling your Remote Action is:

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
  '{!$RemoteAction.Publication_Tab_Controller.update_publication}',
  a,
  handleResult
);
```

Where `a` is your Account object and `handleResult` is the name of a JavaScript callback function that will run when the RemoteAction has completed, like this:

```
function handleResult(result, event) { ... }
```

Comment: I have a question regarding this . Here the 'a' was actually for <apex:pageblockTable value="{!pub}" var="a"> where pub is of type publication and is being accessed from the controller. Can I directly pass it to the Controller method update_publication? @dominic

Comment: No, the a is a visualforce variable tgat doesn't exist in the rendered html page. You will need to use a javascript variable that references the value.

Comment: Hi @dominic I am still having problems with passing the value of the 'a' variable back to the update_publication method. I would be really grateful if you show me a syntax for that. The variable 'a' is actually supposed to contain the value of the publication, the corresponding button of which is being clicked and the popup is being showed